# Calculating shortest path using neural network in a weighted directed graph using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, input, neural-network, shortest-path

I would like to implement neural network to calculate the shortest path in a network represented as  a weighted directed graph in MATLAB.

I have series of questions how to proceed from the beginning.

1. How do I give NN a map/graph as input (Adjacency matrix or Incidence matrix)?
2. How do I execute conditions for shortest path, so that NN understands it?
3. with which information I do training?
4. Once I train the network, can i give any graph as input and it finds shortest path?

I am very new to Neural Networks, i have no clue about inputs, its confusing.

I really need help with the information such as how and what kind of information will be given to NN!

Thank you very much,

Regards,
Sai

Comment: Have you looked at something like this: http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~mandziuk/PRACE/TSP_DM.pdf  or this http://ce.sharif.ir/courses/84-85/2/ce667/resources/root/Seminar_no_7/paper_potvin_nn_tsp.pdf  or this http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/neco.1996.8.2.416 ?  Knowing the keywords can help with document searches.

Comment: Hai, I have read many documents about NN and the question was to use NN for solving shortest path. As i did hard coding the math of NN. It is very clear. soon i will upload my approach in a blog. :) Thanks though!

Comment: if you have a good answer, then put a link or copy as an answer here too.

Comment: Hai, you are correct. here is the link. this journal has published after completion of my work with much more details. if anyone needs this paper, please contact me, i can send a pdf of the paper. Greetigns, Sai http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231216003714